# How do I copy top X files from a directory to another using terminal command?

Tags: command-line

I have a directory more than 1200+ files. How do I copy the top 1000 lines of that directory to another directory?

Comment: By top 1000 files you mean first 1000 files in alphabetical order?

Comment: yes first 1000 files, no order needed for copy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -1000 | xargs cp -t foo_dir` where *foo_dir* is the destination where the files will be copied.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` will look for files, on the current directory only. The output of that will be pipped to the command `head` that will return the top 1000 results. The result of that will be pipped to `xargs` that will use the `cp` command, one per line of results, to copy the files to a destination directory of your choice.

Comment: *cool* glad it works.